# Using Source command from crontab to run script

Tags: scripts, vpn, cron, openvpn

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I have a question regarding generating a CRL file with OpenSSL from the crontab once a month.

I have a script called "gen-crl" that i can run from /opt/vpn/openvpn-ca
Underwater the gen-crl script is located elsewhere, because i created a soft symlink for it:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    27 May 17 22:48 gen-crl -> /usr/share/easy-rsa/gen-crl
```

The gen-crl script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# revoke a certificate, regenerate CRL,
# and verify revocation

CRL="crl.pem"

if [ "$KEY_DIR" ]; then
    cd "$KEY_DIR"

    # set defaults
    export KEY_CN=""
    export KEY_OU=""
    export KEY_NAME=""

    # required due to hack in openssl.cnf that supports Subject Alternative Names
    export KEY_ALTNAMES=""

    # generate a new CRL -- try to be compatible with
    # intermediate PKIs
    $OPENSSL ca -gencrl -out "$CRL" -config "$KEY_CONFIG"
    $OPENSSL crl -text -in "$CRL"
else
    echo 'Please source the vars script first (i.e. "source ./vars")'
    echo 'Make sure you have edited it to reflect your configuration.'
fi
```

The script can only be run if i type "source vars" before i run the gen-crl script.

Now i want to run this script from a cronjob, and now it becomes tricky for me because is have to use "source vars" before running the gen-crl script.

I already tried this in the crontab as a test and reloaded the cron daemon afterwards (service cron reload):

```
*/1 *    * * *   root   source /opt/vpn/openvpn-ca/vars; /opt/vpn/openvpn-ca/gen-crl
```

But that didn't work, because i could see by the timestamp of the crl.pem, that it didnt change.

How can i run this gen-crl script from the crontab by also using the source command?

Comment: `source` is a bashism - by default, cron uses `/bin/sh` so try `. /opt/vpn/openvpn-ca/vars`. I'd also suggest using `&&` in place of `;` here (but that's just a personal preference)

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: ... which should be written `date "+\%F - \%T - no sleep!"` in a crontab of course

Comment: @steeldriver ; you were right; I got it working now.

What I did was trying to do this in the crontab:
`*/1 *    * * *   root   . /opt/vpn/openvpn-ca/vars && /opt/vpn/openvpn-ca/gen-crl`

But this didn't work

So i created a `generate-crl` file in the /etc/cron.daily and `chmod 755` it accordingly.

Then i put this in the `generate-crl` file:

`#!/bin/sh

 

cd /opt/vpn/openvpn-ca
. /opt/vpn/openvpn-ca/vars && /opt/vpn/openvpn-ca/gen-crl`

Now it is working. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

@steeldriver ; you were right; I got it working now.

What I did was trying to do this in the crontab:

`*/1 *    * * *   root   . /opt/vpn/openvpn-ca/vars && /opt/vpn/openvpn-ca/gen-crl`

But this didn't work. So i created a `generate-crl` file in the `/etc/cron.daily` and `chmod 755` it accordingly. Then I put this in the `generate-crl` file:

```
#!/bin/sh     

cd /opt/vpn/openvpn-ca 
. /opt/vpn/openvpn-ca/vars && /opt/vpn/openvpn-ca/gen-crl
```

Now it is working. Thanks for pointing me in right direction!